# get the frame of a view made in IB in viewDidLoad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

When I create a label in Interface Builder and hook the outlet to a viewController, and log the label in viewDidLoad as follows:

> NSLog(@"label: %@",self.label);

It gives me a frame of (0,0,0,0).  self.view gives me a size over 0.  An older program's label also gives me a size over 0.  It will log the text in the label, so it is hooked up right.  Is this a change in Xcode 4.5?  How do I access the frames that I set in Interface Builder?

this is the log:

UILabel: 0x754e1b0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'this is a label'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer =...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the frame layouts are unreliable in `viewDidLoad`. In the case of a nib this shouldn't be a problem. Are you using AutoLayout by any chance ?

Please also log the same values in `viewWillAppear`, this will certainly have the correct values. I usually use `viewWillLoad` to initiate my UI elements, and `viewWillLoad` to place them correctly.

Comment: viewWillAppear gives me a 0 size, but viewDidAppear gives me the real size.

Comment: Thanks! autolayout was the problem.  now the real size shows up in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear and everything else.  I'll have to learn about this autolayout thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"Label Frame: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.label.frame));
```

Comment: Are you sure you have connected the label in Interface Builder?